# python, How to find unique values per category not in any other category

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a dataset that has the following data structure:

```
Company---Issue--Date

Microsoft---Error1--Jan

Microsoft---Error4--Jan

Facebook---Error1--Dec

Facebook ---Error2 --Dec
```

How do I display only the issues that are unique per company and also when these errors occurred. For example return the following:

```
Microsoft Error4 Jan

Facebook Error2 Dec
```

Therefore it is not returning the Error1 as it is in both companies.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `transform` with `nunique`

```
df = df[df.groupby('Issue').Company.transform('nunique')==1]
Out[17]: 
     Company   Issue Date
1  Microsoft  Error4  Jan
3   Facebook  Error2  Dec
```